# How to verify variable is present or not in the page using protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to verify whether particular variable is present or not in the page.

HTML code

```
<script>
        srpTupleJson = [{"name":"Praveen Mishra","title":"B.Tech in Computers Science with 1 year exp. in python\/django","isPremium":false,"isFeatured":false,"isNew":false,"emplo"
</script>
```

I want to verify "srpTupleJson" variable is present in the page or not. How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should be simple .. use `browser.executeScript()` to fetch the variable value into your test and then have an expect

Something as simple as below would do

```
browser.executeScript('return srpTupleJson').then(function _checkValue(value){
//operation you want to perform on the variable value
            console.log(value)
        expect(value).toContain("name");

        })
```

UPDATE: To make things simple, lets say we have to check that the returned value is not `null` , then below statement will do the job

```
    expect(browser.executeScript('return srpTupleJson')).not.toBe(null)
```

Comment: I tried with same and it's not working. It's json data and i  just want to verify "srpTupleJson" variable is present or not in the page. If i use above code i am getting json data . I attached screen shot of error also.Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry i miss guided u i think..I want to verify  "srpTupleJson" text is present or not in the page. Please help me

Comment: yes, sorry I cant understand what you are looking for .. that variable `srpTupleJson` contains loads and loads of data as per the screenshot you attached .. so what do you want to really check? ... do you want to check if each and every json tag is present on the web page? if so then may be you can raise a fresh question .. as its not related to Protractor ... May be bigger audience can help

Comment: Exactly srpTupleJson contains loads and loads of data and only thing i want to verify is "srpTupleJson" variable text is present or not. That's it.

Comment: @raghavendrat does the latest AdityaReddy's suggestion work for you? `expect(browser.executeScript('return srpTupleJson')).not.toBe(null);` - looks exactly what you are asking. It would fail if `srpTupleJson` was never "globally" defined on the page.

Comment: @alecxe yes it's worked. I didn't accept the answer in a hurry. Thnks